# Microsoft JScript compilation error: Syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность

Помогите найти, в чём ошибка. IDE ни на что не ругается, однако при запуске выдаёт синтаксическую ошибку.

```
const body = {
        login: '000',
        password: '000',
        header: 'Test JS script for API',
        text: 'Test JS script for API',
        number: '000'
    };

    fetch('https://sms.beltelecom.by/sites/all/modules/api_sms/xml.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
    });
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь запустить `js` файл в `windows`?

Comment: В тегах node.js, в заголовке почему-то JScript. Вы уж определитесь, чем конкретно вы запускаете скрипт

Comment: при запуске этого кода под nodejs v20 скрипт отрабатывает, выдаёт ответ `{ state_author: null, state_sms: null, id_sms: 6459581 }`, при запуске на nodejs v11 пишет `ReferenceError: fetch is not defined`. А какая ошибка у вас? И какая у вас версия nodejs?

Comment: Microsoft JScript - устаревшая скриптовая машина для администрирования Windows. Запускать на нём современный JavaScript - ошибка.